# CodeIgniter routing always through index.php?

Tags: codeigniter, routes

CodeIgniter beginner here. The base URL of my website is 'http://localhost/routing/'.

```
// config.php
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/routing/';
```

I'm simply trying to route the url 'http://localhost/routing/admin' to the admin controller using the following rules but it doesn't work. Instead I have to use 'http://localhost/routing/index.php/admin'.

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'seasons';
$route['admin'] = 'admin';
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

**Question**: is there a way to remove 'index.php' from the url?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is there a way to remove 'index.php' from the url?

Yes, as well as being a [very popular question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=codeigniter%20remove%20index.php), it is covered [in the CodeIgniter documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html) (which is very good and I highly recommend reading).

Comment: I had to use the following rule though 'RewriteRule (.*)$ index.php' instead of 'RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]'.

Comment: It's nice you provided the link here, although I think CodeIgniter team should remove this weird requirement, or at least explain the thing in their getting started tutorial instead of just pretending it looks normal, as who wants to have "index.php" in the middle of  their url to start with... :S

Comment: @XunYang I was thinking the same thing. But, it got me to look into routing a bit more.

Answer (score 7):

Make changes in .htaccess file and config.php

**application/config.php**

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Comment: This answer is GOOD, but final trick to make this work is to move .htaccess from : 
"yourprojectfolder/application/.htaccess" to "yourprojectfolder/.htaccess"

Answer (score 0):

In your `.htaccess` write this. Also look for additional information : [Codeigniter Guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt) # exceptions
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```